# How do I get zsh's autocomplete to complete wildcards like bash does?

Tags: bash, zsh, globbing

In zsh and in bash, if I type `ls c<TAB>` it displays every filename starting with c.  If instead I type `ls c*<TAB>`, bash behaves the same way, but zsh replaces the `c*` with the list of every file starting with c.  Is there any way to make zsh behave like bash does?

Answer (score 4):

```
setopt GLOB_COMPLETE
```

From `man zshoptions`:

> GLOB_COMPLETE
>
> When the current word has a glob pattern, do not insert all the words resulting from the expansion but generate matches as for completion and cycle through them like MENU_COMPLETE. The matches are generated as if a ‘*’ was added to the end of the word, or inserted at the cursor when COMPLETE_IN_WORD is set. This actually uses pattern matching, not globbing, so it works not only for files but for any completion, such as options, user names, etc.
>
> Note that when the pattern matcher is used, matching control (for example, case-insensitive or anchored matching) cannot be used. This limitation only applies when the current word contains a pattern; simply turning on the GLOB_COMPLETE option does not have this effect.

Comment: That just replaces the pattern with the first match rather than all the matches.  I want to only list the matches.

Comment: If you keep hitting tab, it should cycle through the matches. If it's not also displaying the list of matches, you may have to mess with your zsh completion options.

Comment: I don't want to cycle through options though, I only want to list them.

Comment: @m42a: Did you ever figure out how to do that?

Comment: @m42a you may want to set `menu_complete` and `auto_list`.

Comment: That has the same problem as GLOB_COMPLETE; it inserts the first match as well as listing.